# What is a typical sea-level engine nozzle/expansion ratio? What about vacuum engines?

Tags: engines, engine-design, nozzle

On a sea-Level engine, what is the average nozzle ratio? What about an upper-stage vacuum engine?

Answer (score 4):

It varies widely with the chamber pressure and other details of the engine design. Some examples of first-stage engines with their approximate nozzle ratios:

- [RD-180](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RD-180) (Atlas V) 36:1
- [F-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rocketdyne_F-1) (Saturn V) 16:1
- [Merlin 1D](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merlin_(rocket_engine_family)) (Falcon 9) 16:1
- [SSME](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RS-25) (STS, SLS) 77:1

For ideal performance, [the expansion should reduce the exhaust pressure to be equal to the ambient atmospheric pressure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rocket_engine_nozzle#Aerostatic_back-pressure_and_optimal_expansion), but since first-stage engines operate over a range of altitudes, the expansion ratio must be a compromise.

Note that the SSME on the shuttle burns from liftoff all the way to orbit, so it is tuned more towards vacuum performance than the others, with a higher expansion ratio.

Some upper stage engines:

- [Merlin 1D Vacuum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merlin_(rocket_engine_family)#Merlin_1D_Vacuum) (Falcon 9) 165:1
- [J-2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rocketdyne_J-2) (Saturn V) 27:1
- [RL10](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RL10) (Atlas V, Delta IV) 84:1 or 130:1 depending on model
- [HM7B](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HM7B) (Ariane) 83:1

Since upper stage engines exhaust into near-vacuum, extremely high expansion ratios would be ideal for performance, but the nozzle sizes are constrained by mass and space limitations.

Comment: This does answer the direct question, but I wouldn't mind seeing a brief discussion (or link to such) as to the optimum expansion vs.  atmospheric density.

Comment: Added a bit of info.